# Using the new Toolbar of Android the icons are cut off

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Using the new Toolbar of Android 5 the icons appear cut off! 
I'm using a drawer Navigation and the new toolbar. Any suggestions?

It seems that something it's above the toolbar

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here it is the Drawer Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/gray_light_divider_list_drawerNav"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_light_background_list_drawerNav"
        />
```

Edit: Adding these two attributes in the toolbar 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

IT LOOKS TOO BIG

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the toolbar twice, in the drawer navigation and also in the fragment itself

Answer (score 0):

the height of the toolbar is to small. you should have your toolbar's minHeght as this

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: Adding the above attribute, and with height= "wrap_content" the toolbar looks too big

Comment: that is the recommended height of the toolbar. you see what happens when you dont put what the recommended height is

Comment: no that is not the normal height, something is wrong with your layout

Answer (score 0):

The normal height of the `Toolbar` is 56dp. Try setting the height to that, it should look normal.

Comment: it looks the same :S too big

Comment: I found what it is, I included the toolbar twice, in the drawer navigation and also in the fragment content. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should post your findings as an answer so others can figure this out if they have the same problem.

Comment: Yes I will do it, today